# Same description shows dynamically on corresponding pages. Will it hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engines, duplicate-content, penalty

I am developing an Image Converter site. In their various conversation tools are available like JPG to PNG, PNG to BMP, JPG to BMP etc...

So at converting page lets say you are in JPG to PNG page. I am displaying a description about JPG file format and PNG file format. This description is kept in the DB. So when you change the format it pull the description about those converting file type. Here is a sample.
[image]

This site will have image conversion combinations of 100 or more And the description related to JPG will appear on the pages where JPG to PNG, JPG to BMP, JPG to etc....
so will this affect negatively SEO? like duplicate content?
Note that this is not a blog. This is a tool. So, the tool site's main objective is to provide the service. Not the content.
Am I overthinking? or how to address this?